Mostrar una matriz que ya tiene un dato c #
Como hacer para mostrar esto en la consola como una matriz, no se si es con un for.
busque en todos lado y no especifican cuando ya tenes el dato
double[,] ingresoMensuales = {
 { super1.mes1, super1.mes2, super1.mes3 },
 { super2.mes1, super2.mes2, super2.mes3 },
 { super3.mes1, super3.mes2, super3.mes3 } };

//quiero que salga en consola esta matris


Estas utilizando matrices cuadradas (matriz[,]), yo te recomiento utilizar siempre matrices escalonadas (matriz[][]), estas ultimas cuentas con una mayor cantidad de funciones disponibles, por ejemplo para este caso podrías hacer:
double[][] ingresoMensuales = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]];
Console.WriteLine( string.Join("\n", ingresoMensuales.Select(a=> string.Join("\t", a) )));


Simplemente itera la matriz usando un for:
           double[,] ingresoMensuales = {
            { super1.mes1, super1.mes2, super1.mes3 },
            { super2.mes1, super2.mes2, super2.mes3 },
            { super3.mes1, super3.mes2, super3.mes3 } };

           for (int i = 0; i < ingresoMensuales.GetLength(0); i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < ingresoMensuales.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(ingresoMensuales[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

En el código anterior se hace uso del tabulador para que tu salida al imprimir la matriz sea similar a:
1000    1100    1200    
2000    2100    2200    
3000    3100    3200

También podrías usar simplemente:
   foreach (int i in ingresoMensuales)
   {
    System.Console.Write("{0} ", i);
   }

en este caso obtendrías como salida un elemento seguido del otro, barriendo cada renglón de tu matriz:
1000 
1100 
1200 
2000 
2100 
2200 
3000 
3100 
3200 


muchas gracis @jorgesys yo lo esaba haciedo asi porque no sabia.tambien sirve?
double[,] ingresoMensuales = { { super1.mes1, super1.mes2, super1.mes3 }, { super2.mes1, super2.mes2, super2.mes3 }, { super3.mes1, super3.mes2, super3.mes3 } };
Console.WriteLine("Los ingreso de este mes fueron");
Console.WriteLine("La ganancia son de Super mercado 1: " + "Mes1: " + ingresoMensuales[0, 0] + " Mes2: " + ingresoMensuales[0, 1] + " Mes3: " + ingresoMensuales[0, 2]);

También puede funcionar, solo que solo estas imprimiendo los datos del primer renglon, tendrías que agregar para que imprima los demás renglones. Imagino a penas empiezas a programar en C#, lo que te sugiero iterar usando un for,

si hace dos semanas empecé a programar en c#(nunca programe en ningún lenguaje) y estoy aprendiendo con los ejercicio pero bueno es un progreso. Muchas gracias capo!!!!

Ok Diego, excelente!, tienes poco, un for es usado en una gran mayoría de los lenguajes de programación!  Por esto, inicialmente podrías iniciar usando un for, después usar algo más avanzado como Linq
